# How to distribute subfigures horizontally

Tags: subfloats

I have  a figure with 3 subfigures.

I want there to be white space between them (that's why I set the width to `0.25\textwidth`), but I want them to be distributed horizontally, so that the left edge of the left image aligns with he text border on the left, and the same thing on the right.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[h] % example dataset
    \centering
    \subfigure[Gray overlay.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \subfigure[Green overlay.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \subfigure[Red overlay.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

You can see that there is a white space between the images and the border of the text. I thought using `hfill` would eliminate them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: replacing `\hspace{\fill}` with `\hfill` doesn't work. The solution below that I accepted works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the undesired spaces. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % This is the default in recent LaTeX distros
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe} % Shows the frame, only for this example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[h] % example dataset
    \centering% <-- superfluous in this example as commented by Zarko
    \subfigure[Gray overlay.]{%  <-- No space here
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Green overlay.]{% <-- No space here
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Red overlay.]{%   <-- No space here
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}%      <-- No space here
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\centering` after \`begin{figure}` is superfluous ...

Comment: @Zarko, you are right. Commented in the code. Thanks for pointing it!!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Technically, you are still adding spaces between the subfigure and \hfill, which will only show up if you run out of space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yep you're right, but I didn't find it very important for this example. However, thank you for clarifying it. Better to know what's going on, because the spaces were the OP problem

Answer (score 1):

Mostly off-topic (source of spurious space is already solved by accepted answer) ...

- you use `subfigure` package, which obsolete and replaced with its successor `subfig`, which replace command `\subfigure` with `subfloat`,
- even betteer is to use `subcaption` which in version 1.3 o)or newest) also support `\subfloat` syntax
- command `\hspace{\fill}` can be shortly write as `\hfill`

Considering above mentioned, your MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht] % example dataset
    \subfloat[Gray overlay.]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Green overlay.]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Red overlay.]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]
        {example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block borders)